# How to traverse a flat array in lodash / jquery / vue that has parent-child setup

Tags: recursion, parent-child, lodash, vuejs2

In our project We are using jquery / vue / lodash ...

I am looking for a solution on how to traverse an array. My final goal is to count all ancestors for every node. The data structure is a flat array.

```
a = [{ patriarch , root } , {gran-daddy A , patriarch}, { gran-daddy B , patriarch} , { father 1 , gran-daddy B } , { father 2 , gran-daddy B },
{ father 3 , gran-daddy B }, { child 1 , father 3 } etc....
```

The end result should be:

```
patriarch  13 ancestors
gran-daddy1  7 ancestors
gran-daddy2  6 ancestors
etc....
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain the problem a bit better.

Comment: problem is that i do have an app where i need to display counters. The data structure has a flat structure.  ¨[{Id:1, parentId:0 },{Id:2, parentId:1},{Id:3, parentId:0} , {Id:4, parentId:3}, {Id:5, parentId:4}  etc ...]    The counter indicates for each leaf  how many ancestors there are...  Think about a file system that can have many files ( in several sub folders.) The counter would tell the user how many files he will find in this folder...